# Interlop Word: Incorrect Table Rows Count

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to collect info from more than 800 hundreds of word files with same structure. There is a table in the headnote section. What I need is something in the table. The table has 4 rows, But when I tried to get the row count, it returns 1.

```
        Word.Application m_word =new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Word.Document doc;

        Object filename = treeList1.FocusedNode["SOPName"].ToString();
        Object filefullname = treeList1.FocusedNode["FullPath"].ToString();
        Object confirmConversions = Type.Missing;
        Object readOnly = Type.Missing;
        Object addToRecentFiles = Type.Missing;
        Object passwordDocument = Type.Missing;
        Object passwordTemplate = Type.Missing;
        Object revert = Type.Missing;
        Object writePasswordDocument = Type.Missing;
        Object writePasswordTemplate = Type.Missing;
        Object format = Type.Missing;
        Object encoding = Type.Missing;
        Object visible = Type.Missing;
        Object openConflictDocument = Type.Missing;
        Object openAndRepair = Type.Missing;
        Object documentDirection = Type.Missing;
        Object noEncodingDialog = Type.Missing;

       doc= m_word.Documents.Open(ref filefullname,
                   ref confirmConversions, ref readOnly, ref addToRecentFiles,
                   ref passwordDocument, ref passwordTemplate, ref revert,
                   ref writePasswordDocument, ref writePasswordTemplate,
                   ref format, ref encoding, ref visible, ref openConflictDocument,
                   ref openAndRepair, ref documentDirection, ref noEncodingDialog
                   );
        m_word.Visible =true;
        string msg=string.Empty;

        Word.Table InfoTable =
            doc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Tables[1];
        msg += string.Format("The table has {0} rows，{1} columns.\n", InfoTable.Rows.Count, InfoTable.Columns.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= InfoTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= InfoTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                msg += string.Format("{0},{1}:{2}\n", i, j, InfoTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Try installing the OpenXML Productivity Tool from Microsoft. This will let you examine the make up of the document (and it can show code to generate the document from C#). You may find that             `doc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Tables[1];` isn't the right way to reference the table you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice is very helpful. I got it right now.